# Como construir: click na linha corrente e carregar as informações da linha clicada

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Em meu template há um form e o data-table com as informações "oriundas do form". Minha dificuldade é como implementar que ao clic na linha da tabela faça com que as informações sejam carregadas no form com os devidos dados preenchidos e seus text-fields?

```
<template>
  <v-container class="fundo-container" id="vida-judicial" fluid>
    <v-card class="fieldset" outlined color="#EEEEEE" fluid>
      <v-card-title>
        <p class="font-weight-bold mb-0">Honorários</p>
      </v-card-title>

      <v-container fluid class="pb-0 mb-n4 my-n4">
        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="12" md="1">
            <v-text-field-vee-validate
            />
          </v-col>

          <v-col cols="12" md="3">
            <v-text-field-vee-validate
            />
          </v-col>

          <v-col cols="12" md="3">
            <v-text-field-vee-validate
              label="Valor Final Risco"
            />
          </v-col>

          <v-col cols="12" md="2">
            <v-text-field-vee-validate
              label="Percentual"
            />
          </v-col>

          <v-col cols="12" md="3">
            <v-text-field
              label="Honorários Mínimos"
            />
          </v-col>

          <v-col cols="12" md="12" />
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-card>

    <v-card class="fieldset" outlined color="#EEEEEE" fluid>
      <v-card-title>
        <p class="font-weight-bold mb-0">Consulta</p>
      </v-card-title>

      <v-container fluid class="pb-0 mb-n4 my-n4">
        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="12" md="12">
            <v-data-table
              :headers="headers"
              :items="items"
              hide-default-footer
              class="tabelaHistoricoGeral elevation-1"
              :page.sync="page"
              :items-per-page="5"
              @page-count="pageCount = $event"
            >
              <template v-slot:top>
                <v-toolbar flat color="#EEEEEE">
                  <v-btn
                    color="secondary"
                    @click="editarAgenda = true"
                  >
                    <v-icon class="mr-2">mdi-pencil</v-icon>Editar
                  </v-btn>
                </v-toolbar>
              </template>

              <template v-slot:[`item.checkbox`]="{ item }">
                <v-simple-checkbox v-model="item.checkbox"></v-simple-checkbox>
              </template>
            </v-data-table>
            <v-pagination
              v-model="page"
              color="primary"
              :length="pageCount"
              class="transparent my-pagination"
            ></v-pagination>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-card>
  </v-container>
</template>        

<style scoped>
.v-btn {
  font-weight: 300 !important;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 0.7rem !important;
  width: 150px;
}
</style>
<script>
export default {
  components: {
  },

  data: () => ({
    page: 1,
    pageCount: 0,
   

    headers: [
      {
        text: "",
        align: "start",
        sortable: false,
        value: "checkbox",
        class: "tabelaHistoricoGeralHeader",
      },
      {
        text: "Parcela",
        align: "center",
        sortable: false,
        value: "parcelaa",
        class: "tabelaHistoricoGeralHeader",
      },
      {
        text: "Valor Inicial Risco",
        align: "center",
        value: "valorinicialriscoo",
        class: "tabelaHistoricoGeralHeader",
      },
      {
        text: "Valor Final Risco",
        align: "center",
        value: "valorfinalriscoo",
        class: "tabelaHistoricoGeralHeader",
      },
      {
        text: "Percentual",
        align: "center",
        value: "percentuall",
        class: "tabelaHistoricoGeralHeader",
      },
      {
        text: "Honorários Mínimos",
        align: "center",
        value: "honorariosminimoss",
        class: "tabelaHistoricoGeralHeader",
      }
    ],
    items: [],
    editedIndex: -1,
    editedItem: {
      parcelaa: "",
      valorinicialriscoo: 0,
      valorfinalriscoo: 0,
      percentuall: 0,
      honorariosminimoss: 0,
    },
    defaultItem: {
      parcelaa: "",
      valorinicialriscoo: 0,
      valorfinalriscoo: 0,
      percentuall: 0,
      honorariosminimoss: 0,
    },
  }),

  created() {
    this.initialize();
  },

  methods: {
    initialize() {
      this.items = [
        {
          parcelaa: "1",
          valorinicialriscoo: 159,
          valorfinalriscoo: 6.0,
          percentuall: 24,
          honorariosminimoss: 4.0,
        },
      ];
    },   
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

No vuetify existe um evento chamado `click:row` que você utiliza na tag `v-data-table` onde você pode colocar sua função que irá preencher o model do form com as informações desejadas.

A minha resposta foi baseada nesta [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58025420/how-can-i-add-a-click-event-to-the-v-data-table) e também pode ser encontrada na documentação do data-table do vuetify [aqui](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#events).